# Can't run .py in a different python version

Tags: python

I have this issue where I installed python 3.9 and python 3.10. I want to run some .py file in python 3.9, so naturally I choose open with and browse to python 3.9 .exe file. But for some reasons, it opens up the python.exe from python3.10 folder. Here's the directory:C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39. But it always opens up python.exe from this directory: C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310.

Comment: See https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html#python-launcher-for-windows - you can use the `py` launcher to choose the version you want to use.

Answer (score 1):

Try using py.exe (Python Launcher for Windows).

```
C:\>py -0p
Installed Pythons found by py Launcher for Windows
 -3.10-64        C:\Users\xyz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe *
 -3.9-64         C:\Users\xyz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe 

# You have 3.10 as the default, if you want to use non-default version:
C:\>py -3.9-64 your_script.py
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the absolute path for the python version you want to execute or you can specify the version you want to run. It is done as follow.

> py -version file.py